# ASP.NET Printing (MVC) Word Documents In SharePoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, ms-word

So I have our MVC web application up and running and we'd like to introduce printing into the solution.  We have an interface (using SharePoint Service 3.0) that displays many files (all Word files) for a particular product.  What we'd like to have happen is for the user to checkbox all the files they want to print, select a printer, and go at it.

The checkbox implementation is easy, I'm trying to think of a good print solution (if there is any).  I'm looking for "out of the box" type solutions.  One thing I was thinking about was creating a web service on SharePoint that takes all the files selected, merges them (somehow), and temporarily posts one big doc that, when finished, the client will print, and then the document gets purged.  Not exactly the fastest operation but seems like it could work.

What's your thoughts on an implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of Doc Files do you have?

Are they already in the DocX format?

If so you can merge them quite easy with the documentAPI

Comment: Yes they are, I'll check out that api next.